# How to get emitter running in nodejs express?

Tags: node.js, express, eventemitter, emit

I have a code as such :

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'
const server = express();

server.get('/view', async function (req, res) {
const emitter = new EventEmitter()
emitter.emit('done')
 emitter.on('done', () => {
    console.log('testing is running')
  })
})
```

However upon running it I do not get `'testing is running'` at all.
How can I get emitter to work with express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're emitting the event BEFORE you have the event handler is installed so you miss the event.

Change the order:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'
const app = express();

app.get('/view', async function (req, res) {
    const emitter = new EventEmitter()
    emitter.on('done', () => {
        console.log('testing is running');
    })
    emitter.emit('done');
});
```

EventEmitter events are processed synchronously so you must have any listeners installed before the event occurs or you will miss the event.

You can also try it in just this stand-alone program:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'
const emitter = new EventEmitter()
emitter.on('done', () => {
    console.log('testing is running');
})
emitter.emit('done');
```